# How to retrieve picked quantity for each of the item line in transfer order/sales order using Suitescript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

One of the columns in item list is "Picked" which is a picked quantity for the item line. But, I cannot find its field name. Then,
I try to use the following coding to retrieve picked quantity (quantitypicked) of an item line from Transfer order / Sales Order. But, didn't success as Netsuite returns an undefined value. The method of counting fulfilled quantity in item fulfilment cannot be used as user may input an item in two different item lines.

```
                             var tranrec = record.load({
                                 type: fnRecType, 
                                 id: fnId, 
                                 isDynamic: true,
                             });

                                 tranrec.selectLine({
                                     "sublistId": "item",
                                     "line": 0
                                 });

                                 var ItemPickedQty = tranrec.getCurrentSublistValue({
                                    sublistId: "item",
                                    fieldId: "quantitypicked"
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I certainly use 'quantitypicked' and 'quantitypacked' to count items that are on item fulfillments but not yet shipped.

Does your account have PICKPACKSHIP enabled? Otherwise you can use 'quantityfulfilled'

All of these are from the Sales Order/Transfer Order point of view.

Note that you can step through the lines of an item fulfillment and relate that back to the original sales order. There is an undocumented field 'orderline' on item fulfillments' line sublist.

Comment: I know this is an old post but using the record api in the javascript console to load a sales order in multiple accounts, all of which have pick/pack/ship enabled, quantity picked is not a field that can be used.

quantityavailable: "42"
quantitybackordered: "0"
quantitybilled: "1"
quantitycommitted: "0"
quantityfulfilled: "1"

Answer (score -1):

To get picked quantity, fieldId id 'quantityfulfilled'
In dynamic mode try using:

```
var ItemPickedQty = tranrec.getCurrentSublistValue({
  sublistId: "item",
  fieldId: "quantityfulfilled"
});
```

In non dynamic mode you could use the below

```
var ItemPickedQty = tranrec.getSublistValue({
  sublistId: "item",
  fieldId: "quantityfulfilled",
  line: 0 // line#
});
```

Comment: quantityfulfilled is not quantity picked. fulfilled quantity is only qty that is in shipped status